# Dynamic data filter based on user selection on large dataset

Tags: powerbi, power-automate, powerapps

The source data has 100 billion records and the intention is not to load it all into power bi but to have it filtered by the source database before being presented by a power bi visual.

Each value of the ID field in the source has 1000 records.  Is it possible for the end user of a power bi report to select up to 100 ID values and have a query pull data into power bi dynamically?  We have access to power apps in case it is required to use in combination with power bi for this selection interface.  The end user is not technical, so they just want to select IDs and view reports for their selection.

Comment: Have a look at [Dynamic M query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-M-Query-parameters)